# Is it possible to swap the left and right audio channels on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, headphones

On iPhone is it possible to make the right audio channel play through my left headhpone, and vice versa?

If it can't be done directly through the iPhone Settings, can it be done with a third-party app? If no such app exists, would it technically be possible to create one?

Comment: Headphones are wired specifically to play out of a certain headphone. You are able to switch the wires around to switch which side your sound comes from but I don't see how this would benefit anybody.

Comment: The new Jaybird X2's are designed to be worn in two ways, and one of those ways involves switching over the left and right headphones. It would be good if you could switch the audio channels on the iPhone to counteract the effect his has.

Comment: Apple is a very stingy company when it comes allowing users to customize features or anything with their products. Chances are you will not be able to switch over the auto with any Apple products as they specify most of their products to work seamlessly with other products. You more than likely will not be able to modify the restrictions has in place in their processors or other components.

Comment: Very possibly -- I can do this on my Mac, just wondering if there's a way to do it on my iPhone. It may well be impossible, or it may well only be possible to switch the audio on a per-app basis. But it would be good to know for sure.

Comment: Are you looking to play music on your phone this way, or video, or audio from a third-party app?

Comment: Preferably all the audio the phone played would have the left and right channels switched, but right now, in practice, it would mainly be the Apple Music app and the Overcast podcast app that I'd be wanting to do this with.